# Jquery change checkbox when clicking other checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes like this:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='cat' class='parent' value='cat1' />Category 1</input>
<input type='checkbox' name='foo' class='child' value='1' />SubCategory 1</input>
<input type='checkbox' name='foo' class='child' value='1' />SubCategory 2</input>

<input type='checkbox' name='cat' class='parent' value='cat2' />Category 2</input>
<input type='checkbox' name='foo' class='child' value='3' />SubCategory 3</input>
<input type='checkbox' name='foo' class='child' value='4' />SubCategory 4</input>
```

I would like to change the 'Category 1' checkbox to checked whenever I click it's subcategories without checking the other categories checkbox.

How can I do that?

Comment: Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xPNWu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the data attribute to set the cat. simply get this form the check event of the child elements:

```
    <input type='checkbox' name='cat' class='parent' value='cat1' id="category1" />Category 1</input>
        <input type='checkbox' name='foo' class='child' value='1' data-cat="1" />SubCategory 1</input>
        <input type='checkbox' name='foo' class='child' value='2' data-cat="1" />SubCategory 2</input>
```

....

```
    $('.child').change(function() {
       var cat = $(this).data('cat');
       $('#category' + cat).prop('checked', true);
    });
```

Comment: That is pretty complicated for something that simple

Comment: probably my brain working overtime as simply not done for a while :-), i was thinking there might be more to it probably.

Comment: I think my solution is more elegant if I have to say so myself - it does assume a slight HTML change, but that is a change that makes sense anyway

Answer (score 1):

I made a slight change to your markup and wrapped the sets in a div each.

Now my code will uncheck the parent too if all its child-cats are unchecked and when you check the parent, all child cats are checked/unchecked

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/B2nmy/)

```
$(function() {
  $(".child").on("click",function() {
      $parent = $(this).prevAll(".parent");
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) $parent.prop("checked",true);
      else {
         var len = $(this).parent().find(".child:checked").length;
         $parent.prop("checked",len>0);
      }    
  });
  $(".parent").on("click",function() {
      $(this).parent().find(".child").prop("checked",this.checked);
  });
});
```

Comment: When I click the subcategory 3 it marks the two parents... =\

Answer (score 0):

You can id the subCategories as cat2_1, cat2_2 etc and then access the category element by means of the subcategory element by splitting the id by `_` to obtain the category id.

Answer (score -1):

Other answer

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $("INPUT").click(function () {              
                    if ($(this).attr("class") == "parent") {
                        var v = this.value;             
                        var check = this.checked;
                        var ok = false;

                        $("INPUT").each(function () {
                            if (v == this.value) {  
                                ok = true;
                            } else {                                
                                if (this.name=="cat") ok = false;
                                else if (ok && this.name == "foo") {
                                    this.checked=check;
                                }
                            }

                        });

                    }


                });
            });
```